# How to get value in for loop based on certain element

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement

I have a list. I want to get value from the last finished sentence. Like last "." not first, second or third.

```
lst = ["1st", "2nd", "?", "3rd", ".", "4th", "5th", "6th", ".", "7th", "8th"]
```

I am trying to achieve

```
Output: 1st 2nd? 3rd. 4th 5th 6th.
```

How can I do this by for loop instead of indexing? Indexing won't work because There are unlimited lists and each time last "." position can be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've gotten your question correctly:

```py
lst = ["1st", "2nd", "?", "3rd", ".", "4th", "5th", "6th", ".", "7th", "8th"]
output = []
start_index = 0
for end_index, char in enumerate(lst):
    if char == ".":
        output.extend(lst[start_index:end_index + 1])
        start_index = end_index + 1

print(" ".join(output))
```